# cant boot ubuntu server 18.04, ram exhausted?

Tags: boot, server, ram, postgresql

so i have ubuntu server 18.04, when i try to boot, alot of "depends" fail to start thus i cant boot the server

going to recovery mode i saw one line says memory exhausted, in recovery mode i use `free -m` and `top` i see really my memory is stuck at 7.8GB

top output:

> KiB Mem : 8040724 total, 135060 free, 7873212 used, 32452 buff/cache

last thing i was doing is importing something to PostgreSQL, and it was stuck at around this much, even after finishing the import, so i restarted and never made it back

btw tried

```
#sync; echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
#sync; echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
#sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

still same problem

Comment: I Tried to do memory test from hp bios, says it passes test
tried to boot live ubnutu 20.04 it shows that my used ram is ~700MB and free is 7.xGB
still when i boot to server it takes forever to enter the recovery mode, and still wont boot in normal mode :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, i didnt figure out what i did wrong, so i reinstalled the server. and while doing the steps again i noticed where i did go wrong. 
i was 'following' the steps of this guide: [How to Set Up OpenStreetMap Tile Server on Ubuntu 18.04](https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/openstreetmap-tile-server-ubuntu-18-04-osm)

at one step i should edit `/etc/sysctl.conf`

`sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf`

and add certain value (depending on my setup) to `vm.nr_hugepages`, for guide it was:

`vm.nr_hugepages = 7950`

They use `7950` because they have a lot of virtual memory?. so this value is fetal for my setup!